# HtmlWebpackPlugin use property chunks renders htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css empty

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following settings in my `webpack.config.js`.

I use `chunks` because I need the produced bundles to come in a specific order.

And the below setting works, but my bundled css is not found in `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css` anymore.

```js
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/app/index.html'),
    favicon: 'assets/favicon.ico',

    chunks: [
      'scripts/jquery.js',
      'scripts/angular.js',
      'scripts/angular-animate.js',
      'scripts/uirouter.js',
      'scripts/app.js',
    ],
    chunksSortMode: 'manual',

    hash: true,
    inject: false,
    title: 'App',
    template: path.join(__dirname, '/index.template'),
  }),
];
```

My template looks as following

```html
<% for (var item in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
<link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[item] %>" rel="stylesheet">
<% } %> <-------------- empty when I use chunks

<% for (var item in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.chunks ) { %>
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.chunks[item] %>"></script>
<% } %> <-------------- works, but the output does not have any hash
```

Moreover when I use `chunks` it makes the `hash` property useless since it does not post fix file names with hash anymore.

Is it that suppose to work like that? That is, if I use `chunks` then I need to include the bundled css file in there as well?

**Updated**

Added a small [example](https://github.com/guoliang/stack-questions/tree/master/61232980-htmlwebpackplugin-use-property-chunks-renders-htmlwebpackplugin-files-css-empty) which produces the issue I'm wondering about

Comment: Can you add small github repo with your example that reproduces?

Comment: I could. I will update later with an example tonight

Comment: @felixmosh added a small example now. Check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to specify the chunks (nor the order), webpack will use the import order as the order of the chunks.

So, if you remove `chunks` & `chunksSortMode` & `inject: false`, the HtmlWebpackPlugin will inject the files properly.

I've made a PR to your repo with the fix.

Comment: it's still strange that things are omitted when I use `chunks` and `chunksSortMode`. anyhow after some thinking I eventually went with your solution with exception on that I still use `inject: false` as I want to have the `js/css` includes to be formatted.

Comment: what if you have multiple entries and need a different template name output for each entry, how do you properly tell each template filename which chunks to include